# How to limited copy file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to check .jpg file in the 2nd folder. 2nd folder has some subfolder. if .jpg exist in the subfolder of 2nd folder, I will copy a file from 1st folder to subfolder of 2nd folder based on the base name. I can do this part refer to this answer
[How to copy file based on matching file name using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58179269/11066255)

But I want to do limitation while I copy a file from 1st folder. I will NOT copy the file, if I already copy the same file from 1st folder to 2nd folder 3 times.

This is the code from the reference.

```
$Job_Path = "D:\Initial"
$JobError = "D:\Process"

Get-ChildItem -Path "$OpJob_Path\*\*.jpg" | ForEach-Object {
    $basename = $_.BaseName.Substring(15)
    $job = "$Job_Path\${basename}.png"
    if (Test-Path $job) {
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddhhmmss'
        $dst = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName "${timestamp}_${basename}.gif"
        Copy-Item $job $dst -Force
    }
```

[image]

Anyone can help me to solve this problem please. Thank you.

### Updated

```
$Job_Path = "D:\Initial"
$JobError = "D:\Process"

Get-ChildItem -Path "$OpJob_Path\*\*.jpg" | ForEach-Object {
    $basename = $_.BaseName.Substring(15)
    $job = "$Job_Path\${basename}.png"
    if (Test-Path $job) {
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddhhmmss'
        $dst = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName "${timestamp}_${basename}.gif"
        $Get = (Get-ChildItem -Name "$OpJob_Path\*\*$basename.jpg*" | Measure-Object).Count
        $Get
        if ($Get -eq "3") {
            Write-Host "Continue Other Process"
            NEXT_PROCESS
        } else {
            Write-Host "Less than 3"
        }
        Copy-Item $job $dst -Force
    }
```

Comment: once you have your list of files, you can use  the `Group-Object` cmdlet with a calculated property to group the files. the result will have a `.Count` property  that you can use. [*grin*] something like this >>> `$FileList  | Group-Object -Property {$_.BaseName.Split('_')[-2,-1] -join '_'}` <<< will give you two groups - three `0908_x` & two `0907_y` items.

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey. Thank you for your advice. I really appreciated. But I modify my question, to make it step by step.

Comment: that is a totally  different question. [*grin*] use the `-Directory` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` to get a list of dirs & then iterate thru that to get a list of files in each dir.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Hi... I am sorry, I modified it again. This the real what I need. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Create a hashtable where you increment the copy count for each file and copy only if the count for the given file doesn't exceed your threshold.

Comment: arg! [*frown*] it looks like `AnsgarWiechers` has a workable idea for you. i will go back to lurking.

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey Please look my updated script if you have some idea. Thanks buddy

Comment: @Joe - your use of  random indentation makes reading your code VERY difficult. [*frown*] that said, where does this `$L_NameError` get its value?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey HI, sorry, I forgot to put it. It's a string. I change it

Comment: Hi @AnsgarWiechers . I update my script. But it still copy the file even the same file already copied 3 times. Could you please help me. Thanks

Comment: @Joe - perhaps your test  should be `$Get -ge 3` instead of `$Get -eq "3"` the 2nd is testing against a STRING and requires and exact match.

Comment: @Joe - you STILL have not fixed the random indentation. please load your code into VSCode with the PoSh addon installed & use the `format document` command to see what i mean. ///// when i load your code it shows a red squiggle error marker under  the `{` at the end of line 4. you need to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

`$Get` is not a hashtable, and it's also not keeping track of what's been copied already. You need to define the hashtable outside the loop

```
$copy_count = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path "$OpJob_Path\*\*.jpg" | ForEach-Object {
    ...
}
```

and then update it whenever you copy a file

```
if ($copy_count[$_.Name] -le 3) {
    Copy-Item ...
    $copy_count[$_.Name]++
} else {
    ...
}
```